# Use a prop function inside useEffect return: prop.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js

I am currently trying to build an next.js app.

So what I want to do is passing a function to a component and call it with useEffect

I have the following component in order to change the props of the parents element. Therefore I pass the function from the parent like this:

```
<NumberInput name="height" update={manuelUpdate}></NumberInput>
```

The manuelUpdate function is a another props function from the actual parent:

```
const manuelUpdate = (name, value) => {
    props.update(name, value);
};
```

It works fine if I run the props.function with the onclick functions. However as soon as I try to use it in useEffect, it returns that the function is not a function.
Maybe I am just thinking to complicated..

this is the component;

```
const NumberInput = ({ name, min = undefined, max = undefined, ...props }) => {
   
    const minInput = min !== undefined
        ? min
        : null;

    const maxInput = max !== undefined
        ? max
        : null;

    const [numb, setNumb] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.update)
    }, [numb]);

    const increaseNumb = () => {
        if (numb < maxInput || maxInput == null) {
            setNumb(numb + 1)
        }
        props.update(name, numb)
    };

    const decreaseNumb = () => {
        if (numb < minInput || minInput == null) {
            setNumb(numb - 1)
        }
    };

    const changeHandler = ({ e }) => {
        let n = parseInt(e.target.value)
        if (Number.isNaN(n)) {
            setNumb(numb)
        } else {
            setNumb(n)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.def_number_input, styles.number_input}>
            <button onClick={decreaseNumb} className={styles.minus}></button>
            <input className={styles.quantity} name="quantity" value={numb} onChange={(e) => changeHandler({ e })}
                type="number" />
            <button onClick={increaseNumb} className={styles.plus}></button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

sorry in advance if my question is stupid or my code messy, I am still in the process of learning :D

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right, but here is what I think. `manuelUpdate` is a function in the parent of `NumberInput`. So when you write `props.update(name, value);` inside the body, it means call the `props.update` function of the parent with those arguments, not the child. Compiler looks for `update` function in the lexical scope of the `manuelUpdate` definition, and not the place it is called.

Comment: that shouldn't be the problem since I can the function everywhere else. For Example calling the function in the const decreaseNumb is no problem. :/

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to another problem. I was accidentally calling the component 2 times and forgot to adjust the parameters. **CASE CLOSED**